# What is causing this undefined constant error?

Tags: php

I have the following underfined constant error:

test.php:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant APP_ID - assumed 'APP_ID' in 
/var/www/_calls/config.php on line 3
```

Relevant lines of code:

test.php:

```
require_once('config.php');
```

config.php:

```
define(APP_ID, 'Your app name');
```

Comment: When you decided which lines _you_ think are relevant, you did so while making the same mistake you made when writing the code, which has caused the bug. Consequently, we can't see here what you did wrong. Construct and display your [_testcase_](http://sscee.org) so we can see what's _really_ going on. _(edit: you're in luck: the bug is right here after all. You should still learn to make testcases!)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
 define('APP_ID', 'Your app name');
```

Answer (score 3):

You define constants with a string. You cannot use the constant to define the constant because the constant is not yet defined:

```
define('APP_ID', 'Your app name');
```

It's only after you've defined the constant that you can refer to it as `APP_ID` instead of `'APP_ID'`.

See [`define`](https://www.php.net/define), which accepts `string $name , mixed $value...`